# How to establish the estimate?

Tags: calculus, inequality, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, estimation

I consider the inequality as follows: let $a>0,b>0$, and satisfy $$2a^2-b^2\leq C(1+a).\tag{1}$$ If we assume that $b\leq a$, then there exist a constant $C_1>0$ such that $$a\leq C_1\tag{2}$$ by solving the quadratic inequality $$a^2-Ca-C\leq 0.\tag{3}$$ where $C_1:=\frac{C+\sqrt{C^2+4C}}{2}.$

Now if we instead of $b \le a$ just assume that $b\leq C_1$, can we conclude that also $$a\leq C_1.\tag{4}$$ holds? (Actually, I wish $(4)$ is true.)

Any answer will be appreciated!

Comment: This is a really strange selection of tags. pde? sobolev-spaces?

Comment: @mrf: Actually，the above problem I posted is extracted from context on a priori estimate for a certain PDE. So I wish the people who have rich experience on PDE also concern this question. The same reasoning for the tag "sobolev-spaces".

Comment: Is (4) supposed to be the same as (2)?

Comment: @anonymous: the constant $C_1$ in right hand side maybe differ from (2) to (4).

Answer (score 2):

Such a constant does not exist. Take $b$ very close to 0, and we know that $ \frac {2a^2} {1+a}$ is unbounded. Hence, given any $C$, we can find an $a$ (large enough) and a $b$ (close to 0) such that $2a^2 - b^2 > C (1+a)$.

---

If $a$ is fixed, then you can simply take $C_a = \frac {2a^2}{1+a}$.

Comment: @ Calvin Lin: Thank you for your answer! But,for mathematical reasoning，we assume that there exists $C>0$ such that $(1)$ holds,and then we need to prove that there exists $C_1>0$ such that the statement “if $b\leq C_1$, then $a\leq C_1$” is true. Namely we want to prove $(4)$ not $(1)$. :)